# Why does DSolve return the same DSolve expression?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am trying to find the closed solution for the classic chemostat model with one species and one resource (Monod response) using the DSolve() function. However, after running for 10 minutes, I get back the same equation back.

```
In:
DSolve[{ x'[t] == (x[t]*rmax *R[t])/(k - R[t]) - D, 
R'[t] == D *(S - R[t]) - (rmax *x[t]*R[t])/(k - R[t])}, 
{x[t], R[t]}, t ]
```

10 minutes later

```
Out:
DSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -D + (rmax R[t] x[t])/(k - R[t]), 
Derivative[1][R][t] == D (S - R[t]) - (rmax R[t] x[t])/(k - R[t])},
{x[t], R[t]}, t]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To start with, [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) is a "reserved word" and cannot be used as a user-defined symbol. You will probably need to assign values to the parameters and use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

Comment: There is no known closed form solution for this model; as @BobHanlon says, you'll need to use `NDSolve` instead.  BTW, the first equation should have `-d*x[t]` instead of `-d` and the Monod function is `R[t]/(k+R[t])` not `R[t]/(k-R[t])`.

Comment: Maybe you're only looking for equilibria?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out the errors! And sadly, I am interested in non-equilbrium dynamics. Thank you for pointing out that there is no known closed solution. Indeed, I have been unable to find one in the literature and figured I would have a go at it in Mathematica.